# Load class from properties file

Tags: micronaut

Given a class and a related properties file, what is the simplest approach to automatically load the values in a micronaut application. 
How do you associate the properties file with the class and make it set the properties?

```
public class MyPropertyClass {
    @Value("${value1}")
    private String value1;

    @Value("${value2}")
    private String value2;

    public MyPropertyClass() {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

e.g.

```
file: resources/my-props.properties

value1=my value 1
value2=my value 2
```

Comment: What is the use case for that? There is an 'application.yaml' file used in the Micronaut to load configuration properties where you can simply use own configuration classes where fields ale automatically filled in by the definition.

Comment: I know, but I want to provide separation of the properties files.

Comment: Do you want the config file to only be applicable to an instance of that class, or do you want the contents of that config file merged with the rest of the application config?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to be applicable only to the instance of the class.

Comment: "Ideally I'd like it to be applicable only to the instance of the class." - There is no explicit support in Micronaut for that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JeffScottBrown. You mentioned in your original answer "or do you want the contents of that config file merged with the rest of the application config" … is that something that micronaut supports?

Comment: Yes.  The particulars depend on the requirements but a good starting point is taking a look at the property source info at  https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.2/guide/index.html#propertySource